# Create Directory Permissions

Tags: c, windows

I would like to know something about directory creation in C.

I know in unix based systems, you can create a directory with this function:

```
mkdir (const char* directory_name,mode_t mode);
```

but, in windows, mkdir function, only accept one argument, the name of the directory.
you cannot specify mode bits for access permissions.

in windows the function for creating the directory is:

```
_mkdir (const char* directory_name);
```

so, a portable way to creating a directory is like:

```
#ifdef WIN32
      _mkdir (directory_name);
#else
       mkdir (directory_name,mode);
#endif
```

my question is, is there a way to specify permissions like mkdir in unix, but in windows?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363855%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and supply the appropriate [`SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (the linked example uses the security descriptor and attributes for a registry key, but fundamentally this is no different than for a file).

Answer (score 0):

You can set permissions with `CreateDirectory`, from the API Windows.

Answer (score 0):

On windows there also is the `chmod()` analogon `_chmod()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z319a54%28v=vs.100%29.aspx